# jQuery add css style to link list dynamically

Tags: jquery

list of link. required when we click it changes its color i.e highlight active link...
I can't use css as this page is not refreshing. Want to highlight current link.

**HTML**

```
<table border="0">
    <tr style=" width: 100px;">
        <td>
            <div class="overMe">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="leftList">link 1</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" width: 100px;">
        <td>
            <div class="overMe">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="leftList">link 2</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" width: 100px;">
        <td>
            <div class="overMe">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="leftList">link 3</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr> </table>
```

**​CSS**

```
a {
    color: darkgreen;   
}


.selected {
     color: red;   
}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overMe a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.overMe a').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
})
```

​EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/TL9rh/

Comment: What's the problem?  It does exactly what you've described (for me).

Comment: @Archer The example has different markup. See my answer with jsfiddle

Comment: i want it to work with above HTML code .... SEE this http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/aTsJQ/3/   it remains colored...   :(

Comment: Yeah, I see that now - thanks :)

Comment: @PreetJollyChandigarh See my answer. This is using the HTML from your question, not your jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.not(this)`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.overMe a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/TL9rh/65/

Comment: It selects all `.overMe a` except the one you clicked (eg. **this** one)

Answer (score 3):

You can just simplify things

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overMe a').click(function(){
        $('.overMe a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use `this`instead of `.overMe a` when you remove the class

Comment: @ShogunArts.de No you can't. Using `this` will just remove the class from the element being clicked.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de no then its not working See this http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/TL9rh/67/

Comment: ahh, sorry, you're right. Was a error in reasoning. Had some other code in mind :)